# Submitting a form after validating with jquery validator on a button not in form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have been battling with what is wrong on this code since. It so happens that the form is not submitting on this button. The button is of type button and not in the form tag.

```js
$("#step1Btn").click(function () {

  var userForm = $("form[name='step1Form']");

  if (userForm.valid()) {
    userForm.submit(function () {
      console.log('submitted o!')
      $("#spin1").show();
      $("form[name='step1Form'] > span").remove();
      $('input[name="emailInput"]').prop('name', "id")
      $('input[name="fullNameInput"]').prop('name', "full-name")
      $('input[name="phoneInput"]').prop('name', "phone-number")

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "api/v1/user?" + $(this).serialize(),
        success: (result) => {
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(result))
          localStorage.setItem('authToken', result.authToken);
          $("form[name='step1Form'] > span").remove()
          $('#step1, #step2').toggle();
          $('#step1Title, #step2Title').toggle();

        },
        error: function (request, exception, errorThrown) {
          $("form[name='step1Form'] > span").remove();
          $("form[name='step1Form']").prepend('<span class=\'error\'><p>' + request.responseJSON.message + '</p></span>')
        },
      })
    });
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Below is the complete form

```html
<div id="step1" class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <form name="step1Form">
        <div class="home-icon d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
            <img src="images/new-icons/user.png" alt="User Registration logo" height="80" />
            <p class="my-3">User Registration</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fullNameInput">Contact full name</label>
            <input name="fullNameInput" class="form-control custom-input" placeholder="First name    Last name" id="fullNameInput">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="emailInput">Contact email address</label>
            <input name="emailInput" type="email" placeholder="example@email.com" class="form-control custom-input" id="emailInput">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirmEmailInput">Confirm contact email address</label>
            <input name="confirmEmailInput" type="email" placeholder="example@email.com" class="form-control custom-input"
                id="confirmEmailInput">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Contact phone number</label>
            <input name="phoneInput" placeholder="08012345678" class="form-control custom-input" id="phone">
        </div>

    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn red-btn user-btn custom-btn" id="step1Btn">Next<i id="spin1" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></button>
</div>
```

So I would like to see where I went wrong. I am able to log and see output whenever i place a console.log in between the if(userForm.valid) and the userForm.submit().

But as soon as i place it in the userform.submit() I do not get any value back. Like, the form is totally not submitting. I dont know if its because of how I made my Ajax call.. Please Help

Comment: Please update your code what you use on your userForm.valid()

Comment: userform.valid() return true. That step works, Its the submit function that doesnt get called at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting Ajax inside of a `submit`....

```
$("#step1Btn").click(function () {

  ....

  if (userForm.valid()) {

    userForm.submit(function () {

      ....

      $.ajax({ ....
```

Which makes no sense since Ajax replaces the actual submit.  By doing this you are effectively sending it through validation again;  I can't see the `.validate()` method, but suspect that you are simply using the default option, which would be yet another regular `submit`... you're probably stuck in a loop going nowhere.

[The best place for your Ajax would be inside the `submitHandler` of the `.validate()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler).

If your button is outside of the form, you capture the `click` and manually trigger a submit, which then lets the validation plugin take over the rest.

```
$("#step1Btn").click(function () { // click of external button
    $("form[name='step1Form']").submit();  // trigger validation & submission
});

$("form[name='step1Form']").validate({  // initialize plugin
    submitHandler: function(form) { // fires when valid
        //  YOUR AJAX GOES INSIDE HERE
        return false;
    },
    // other options, rules, etc.
});
```

[Read the documentation for the `submitHandler`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler).

Comment: Awesome Man! Thank you!